# Force a user to use a specified session

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, session, kiosk

I've looked everywhere and can't find how to do the following:

What I have is Ubuntu 14.04 desktop 32bit configured with two accounts, one admin and one to run a web kiosk. I have set up a new desktop entry and kiosk script and all is running well.

I set up auto login with `sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

```
autologin-user=kiosk    
autologin-user-timeout=10
```

Which works fine if you allow it to auto boot, but not only can you choose the user (which I need) you can also choose to boot with the kiosk user and change the session to the default ignoring my script.

Is there a way to force a user to always boot with a particular session, but allow other users to choose? I don't want to force the admin account to use the kiosk session.